# Failed to create project in firebase using ternimal in VS code

Tags: flutter, firebase

I was creating a project in firebase using VS Code terminal and I encountered a error

Here is the error

```
D:\Flutter Project\Free code camp tutorial\Dart Tutorial\learningdart> flutterfire configure
i Found 0 Firebase projects.
✔ Enter a project id for your new Firebase project (e.g. my-cool-project) · myflutterproject-learningdart                                                                               
New Firebase project myflutterproject-learningdart created successfully.
FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
COMMAND: firebase projects:create myflutterproject-learningdart --json
ERROR: Failed to create project. See firebase-debug.log for more info.
```

I tried  logging out and logging back in but still error persists.

Comment: The error is telling you to "See firebase-debug.log for more info".  Did you do that?  What does it say? Please edit the question to show more complete details.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the log of the error?

Try This `Flutter Clean`
And Then Try To Relogin

After That run `flutterfire configure`